# SQL LEFT-JOIN on 2 fields for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a view `A` and a view `B`.

In `A` I have a lot of information about some systems, like `IP` and `port` which I want to preserve all. In `B` I have just one information that I want to add at `A`.

The matching fields between the two views are `IP` and `Port`. So I have to match those hosts which has the same IP and Port in both views.

Examples:

#### View A:

```
IP | OS     | Hostname | Port | Protocol
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 80   | tcp 
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 443  | tcp 
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 8080 | tcp 
2  | Linux  | hostTWO  | 21   | tcp
2  | Linux  | hostTWO  | 80   | tcp
3  | Linux  | hostTR   | 22   | tcp
```

#### View B:

```
IP | Port | State
1  | 443  | Open
2  | 80   | Closed
```

#### OUTPUT

```
IP | OS     | Hostname | Port | Protocol | State
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 80   | tcp      |
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 443  | tcp      | Open
1  | Win    | hostONE  | 8080 | tcp      |
2  | Linux  | hostTWO  | 21   | tcp      | Closed
2  | Linux  | hostTWO  | 80   | tcp      |
3  | Linux  | hostTR   | 22   | tcp      |
```

Note: Is possible that some hosts of the view A has no IP/Port related items in View B.

Is also possible that some hosts of the view A has some match in the View B.

I thought that I should be using LEFT JOIN in order to have all the entry of View A and the correct associated entry of View B, but it didn't work.
I'm not able to adjust the query with the right WHERE clause and JOIN solution.

Any idea?

Comment: what did you tried? Show us example of your code

Comment: What your `WHERE` clause contains?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
select a.ip, a.os, a.hostname, a.port, a.protocol,
       b.state
from a
left join b on a.ip = b.ip 
           and a.port = b.port
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the double = in the ON clause that I was missing!

Answer (score 6):

Let's try this way:

```
select 
    a.ip, 
    a.os, 
    a.hostname, 
    a.port, 
    a.protocol, 
    b.state
from a
left join b 
    on a.ip = b.ip 
        and a.port = b.port /*if you has to filter by columns from right table , then add this condition in ON clause*/
where a.somecolumn = somevalue /*if you have to filter by some column from left table, then add it to where condition*/
```

So, in `where` clause you can filter result set by column from right table only on this way:

```
...
where b.somecolumn <> (=) null
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the detail on the WHERE clause.