# MySQL left join on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables in panel data form and I would like to join them on id and year.
table `table1`

```
id  year    col1
---------------------
1   2008    1674.9240
1   2009    1714.4611
1   2010    2470.0510
1   2011    3524.2649
1   2012    3536.4431
1   2013    3694.0000
1   2014    3812.0000
1   2015    4788.0000
1   2016    8316.0000
1   2017    8036.0000
1   2018    10899.0000
1   2019    11092.0000
```

table `table2`

```
id  year    col2
----------------
1   2010    2
1   2013    2
1   2016    15
1   2017    6
```

However the right table has some data lost so I want to left join them so that I can have a result like this:

```
id  year    col1         col2
-----------------------------
1   2008    1674.9240  
1   2009    1714.4611
1   2010    2470.0510    2
1   2011    3524.2649
1   2012    3536.4431
1   2013    3694.0000    2
1   2014    3812.0000
1   2015    4788.0000
1   2016    8316.0000    15
1   2017    8036.0000    6
1   2018    10899.0000
1   2019    11092.0000
```

I tried as other answers said like

```
select a.id, a.year, a.col1, b.col2 from table1 a
    left join table2 b on a.id=b.id and a.year=b.year;
```

but the result turns out to be like this

```
id  year    col1        col2
----------------------------
1   2010    2470.0510   2
1   2013    3694.0000   2
1   2016    8316.0000   15
1   2017    8036.0000   6
```

it shouldn't be like this as another answer shows [different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914698/sql-left-join-on-2-fields-for-mysql).
The MySQL version is MySQL 8.0.22, running on macOS Big Sur 11.1 beta with an Apple M1 chip.

Comment: MySQL (and some other DBMSs) allows the next syntax `ON (table1.id, table1.year) = (table2.id, table2.year)` which seems to be clear enough.

Comment: *but the result turns out to be like this* Looks like real query contains not shown WHERE condition by some `table2` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct:

```
select a.id, a.year, a.col1, b.col2
from table1 a left join
     table2 b
     on a.id = b.id and a.year = b.year;
```

By definition, this returns all rows in `a`, even if there is no match.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=882d7406f58a9756a2d43a66bac4f7ec) is a db<>fiddle.

Perhaps something else is going on -- such as a `where` clause filtering out the non-matches.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I didn't add any `where` clause, my query is just the same as I showed above. I run the query in Navicat 15, maybe it's the Navicat problem?

Comment: @FacelessMage . . . It should be passing the query through as you write it.  Are you sure the data is correct?

Comment: I tried again and found out the query is working correctly, I made a mistake that I didn't go thorough all the result. I have 40000+ rows in my result and MySQL automatically sort the result that all rows with null in col2 are far below. Thank you again!